# How to open a page inside another page in ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, navigation

Can you please tell me. I'm getting data from a database and want to display it on a page. But I want to get it in a certain form. To do this, I send them to a page with a form. And I can't get it back to the main page. Can you tell me where the error is. Thank you in advance.

Home page conclusion Orders.html

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding" >
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let order of orders">
        <app-order [order]="order"></app-order>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Orders.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


export interface Orders {
  reservationDate: Date,
  adultsNumber: Number,
  childrenNumber: Number,
  checkInDate: Date,
  checkOutDate: Date,
  totalPrice: Number,

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bookings',
  templateUrl: './bookings.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bookings.page.scss'],
})
export class BookingsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  orders: Orders[] = []


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Orders[]>('http://localhost:3000')
    .subscribe(order => {
      console.log('Response', this.orders)
      this.orders = this.orders
    })

  }
```

Form page order.html

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-card class="order mb-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <span class="nav-link text-dark"
              [class.active]="activeTab == 'general'"
              [attr.aria-current]="activeTab == 'general'"
              (click)="activeTab = 'general'"
              role="button">
                  General
              </span>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <span class="nav-link text-dark"
              [class.active]="activeTab == 'users'"
              [attr.aria-current]="activeTab == 'users'"
              (click)="activeTab = 'users'"
              role="button">
                  Users
              </span>
          </li>
      </ul>

  <div *ngIf="activeTab == 'general'">
      <ion-list class="card" >
        <ion-item lines="none">
          <ion-label class="completed">Check-in {{orders. checkInDate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item lines="none">
          <ion-label class="completed">Check-out {{orders. checkOutDate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="completed">Number of guests {{orders. adultsNumber}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item lines="none">
          <ion-label class="completed">Check-in {{orders. totalPrice}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="completed">Number of guests {{orders. prepayment}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item lines="none">
          <ion-label class="completed">Total Price {{orders. reservationDate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item lines="none">
          <ion-label class="completed">Prepayment {{orders. reservationDate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </div>
  </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

order.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface Orders {
  reservationDate: Date,
  adultsNumber: Number,
  childrenNumber: Number,
  checkInDate: Date,
  checkOutDate: Date,
  totalPrice: Number,

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.page.scss'],
})
export class OrderPage implements OnInit {
  @Input() order: Orders


activeTab = "general"


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.order)
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your `Home page conclusion Orders.html` ts file code?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, in the order.ts file your are using `order` as input variable but in the order.html file your are using `orders` as a variable name.

If this is not the case, please provide more details that clarifies your issue.